# How to retrieve data from an object in a simple way?

Tags: jquery

I have an object, which contains 2 name parameters - see the example below. I understand that to reach the data I need to loop through the object, but I feel this is too annoying. Is there a better way to get the data in simple way?

```
var obj = {[[[{name:'one'},{name:'two'}]]]};

$.each(obj,function(i,val){
    var first = [] // i will get first time
    $.each(first, function(i, val){
        var second = [] //i will get second time and third later fourth  // like so?
    })
})
```

Does this mean that I should loop the `each` function four times to get the `name` values? If so which is the right way to get that? Is there any way to use the same function to get the data?

Comment: I assume in practice you're not going to have unnecessary nesting of arrays like in the example?

Comment: not like that, i got a chance that has 2 no.of array declared

Comment: That's not a valid object.  The outermost array is a value without a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your `obj` is invalid.

So, try something this:

```
var obj = [[[{
        name: 'one'},
    {
        name: 'two'}]]];

$.each(obj[0][0], function() {
  alert( this.name );
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FnG3Q/1/)**

---

### Another one (for any level of array)

```
var obj = [[[{
    name: 'one'},
{
    name: 'two'}]]];

function getObject(obj) {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[0]) == '[object Array]') {
        getObject(obj[0]);
    } else {
        $.each(obj, function() {
            alert(this.name);
        });
    }
}

getObject(obj);​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FnG3Q/3/)**

---

#### Note

`{}` always contains data with `key : value` pair. So, in your case `{ [ .. ] }` is invalid format of object. some correct formats of object may be:

```
{ key1: value1, key2: value2, .. }

{ data: [{key1: value1}, {key2: value2}] }
```

### Suggestion

If you've option then change the format of your `obj` like below:

```
var obj = [
   { name: 'one' },
   { name: 'two' }
];
```

And try following code simply:

```
$.each(obj, function() {
  alert( this.name );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should search with a recursive function. You can through your object with n tables.

```
var obj = [[[[{name:'one'},{name:'two'}]]]];

function troughTables(table){
    if(table instanceof Array && table.length == 1){
        troughTables(table[0]);
        return;
    }

    console.log("here is a content table");
}

troughTables(obj)
```

With this you can have much tables but the condition is the length must be 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize this object to JSON and get data with regexp.

Also you can use to flatten arrays:

```
jQuery.map(obj, function(n){return n})
```

And you will get result like:

```
[{name:'one'},{name:'two'}]
```